# MongooseError: Not able to connect Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am making a web application. I am using Nodejs, Express and Mongoose. When I run `npm run dev` I am getting these following errors.

```
(node:34525) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/New Project/ecommerce-rest-apis-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:694:11)
    at _mongoose._promiseOrCallback.cb (/home/New Project/ecommerce-rest-apis-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:351:10)
    at Promise (/home/New Project/ecommerce-rest-apis-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/New Project/ecommerce-rest-apis-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Proxy.Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/New Project/ecommerce-rest-apis-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
    at Proxy.Mongoose.connect (/home/New Project/ecommerce-rest-apis-node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:350:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/New Project/ecommerce-rest-apis-node/server.js:11:10)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
(node:34525) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

My `server.js`

```
import express from 'express';
import { APP_PORT, DB_URL } from './config';
import errorHandler from './middlewares/errorHandler';
const app = express();
import routes from './routes';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import path from 'path';
import cors from 'cors';

// Database connection
mongoose.connect(DB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('DB connected...');
});

global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', routes);
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
  <h1>Welcome to E-commerce Rest APIs</h1>
  `);
});

app.use(errorHandler);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || APP_PORT;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}.`));
```

I am making a web application. I am using Nodejs, Express and Mongoose. When I run `npm run dev` I am getting these following errors. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting an import from ./config. provide console.log of DB_URL before connecting to the DB.
Also you can try hardcoding your DB_URL as a first parameter in mongoose.connect() function and check if connection is valid

Comment: You're importing a connection string from config file. Try not to import it and just copy it from config and paste in place of your DB_URL in mongoose.connect() method